# VSTO Outlook Add-In - Handler to Sent Items not always work

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an outlook addin that handles some type of sent emails. For some kind of email users must fill a form with some info and then the app export the email as MSG to a directory tree in filesystem

i have a ribbon with a button that sets a flag ( userproperty) to the sent email so the addin knows which email must be saved:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oProperties As Outlook.UserProperties
    Dim oProperty As Outlook.UserProperty


    oMail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem


    If Not oMail Is Nothing Then

        oProperties = oMail.UserProperties
        oProperty = oProperties.Add("SALVARAPIGES", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo)
        oProperty.Value = True
        oMail.Save()
        oMail.Send()
    Else
        MsgBox("Err")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

In the addin startup, i have (snippet):

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    Dim sentItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim sentFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim paisapiges As String
    Dim aux As String()
    Dim ns As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace

    apigesIsLoaded = True

    'adiciono um trigger para que sempre que for enviado um email e for do tipo SALVARAPIGES, ele fará o tratamento de salvar o email.
    sentFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
    sentItems = sentFolder.Items
    AddHandler sentItems.ItemAdd, AddressOf itemadd
```

and my itemadd routine :

```
Sub itemadd(ByVal NewEmailItem As Object)
    Dim oProperties As Outlook.UserProperties
    Dim salvaApiges As Boolean
    Dim sentMessageItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(NewEmailItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim mainForm As New formSalvarApiges()

    salvaApiges = False
    If Not sentMessageItem Is Nothing Then
        oProperties = sentMessageItem.UserProperties
        For Each pr As Outlook.UserProperty In oProperties
            If pr.Name = "SALVARAPIGES" Then
                salvaApiges = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If salvaApiges Then
            mainForm.txtAssunto.Text = sentMessageItem.Subject
            mainForm.sAction = "Acao01"
            mainForm.sEntryId = sentMessageItem.EntryID
            mainForm.ShowDialog()
            mainForm.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

as you can see whenever a email has this "SALVARAPIGES" userproperty it must be saved to MSG in a directory tree. But half users are saying this does not work ( THE FORM IS NOT POPPED), but whenever i test it, it works. I'm very new to VSTO and all concepts behind it...can anyone just point me the direction?

I have tried using the NameSpace.SendAndReceive method, but they keep complaining.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that raises the events (sentItems) is declared as a local variable. As soon as GC kicks in, it gets released and no more events are raised. Declare the variable on the class level to make sure it stays alive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the source object at the class level to prevent it from swiping by the garbage collector:

```
Dim sentItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
 Dim sentFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim paisapiges As String
 Dim aux As String()
 Dim ns As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace

 apigesIsLoaded = True

 'adiciono um trigger para que sempre que for enviado um email e for do tipo SALVARAPIGES, ele fará o tratamento de salvar o email.
 sentFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
 sentItems = sentFolder.Items
 AddHandler sentItems.ItemAdd, AddressOf itemadd
```

Comment: thank you for your more complete answer, but the first answer is still enough to solve the problem, so i will give him the credit. But thank you a lot!